# Java String Regex Divide - Always the Same Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I never understood how to make properly regex to divide my Strings.
I have this types of Strings `example = "on[?a, ?b, ?c]";`
Sometimes I have this, Strings `example2 = "not clear[?c]";`

For the first Example I would like to divide into this:

```
[on, a, b, c]
```

or

```
String name = "on";
String [] vars = [a,b,c];
```

And for the second example I would like to divide into this type:
[not clear, c]
or

```
String name = "not clear";
String [] vars = [c];
```

Thanks alot in advance guys ;)

Comment: Well I know that I could do this in various steps, first by looking char by char till the [ then I would have the name and on the rest the vars, and then Would the same for the vars, looking char by char.. But I guess that would be very bad performance :s
Thanks for your reply by the way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the character set of your identifiers, you can simply do a split on all of the text that *isn't* in that set.  For example, if your identifiers only consist of word characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`) you can use:

```
String[] parts = "on[?a, ?b, ?c]".split("[\\W]+");
String name = parts[0];
String[] vars = Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length);
```

If your identifiers only have A-Z (upper and lower) you could replace `\\W` above with `^A-Za-z`.

I feel that this is more elegant than using a complex regular expression.

*Edit:* I realize that this will have issues with your second example "not clear".  If you have no option of using something like an underscore instead of a space there, you could do one split on `[?` (or substring) to get the "name", and another split on the remainder, like so:

```
String s = "not clear[?a, ?b, ?c]";
String[] parts = s.split("\\[\\?"); //need the '?' so we don't get an extra empty array element in the next split
String name = parts[0];
String[] vars = parts[1].split("[\\W]+");
```

Comment: The second option worked very well, with all the cases! Thanks alot!
I hope that one day I will understand the regex thing :P
Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2):

This comes close, but the problem is the third remembered group is actually repeated so it only captures the last match.

```
(.*?)\[(?:\s*(?:\?(.*?)(?:\s*,\s*\?(.*?))*)\s*)?]
```

For example, the first one you list `on[?a, ?b, ?c]` would give group 1 as `on`, 2 as `a` 3 as `c`.  If you are using perl, you could the `g` flag to apply a regex to a line multiple times and use this:

```
my @tokens;
while ( my $line =~ /\s*(.*?)\s*[[,\]]/g ) {
    push( @tokens, $1 );
}
```

*Note, i did not actually test the perl code, just off the top of my head. It should give you the idea though*

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but got my question already answered :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] parts = example.split("[^\\w ]");
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (!"".equals(parts[i]) && !" ".equals(parts[i])) {
            x.add(parts[i]);
        }   
    }
```

This will work as long as you don't have more than one space separating your non-space characters. There's probably a cleverer way of filtering out the null and " " strings.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but got my question already answered :)

Comment: I think my answer is more general. Oh, well... ;)